# Permutation polygon

Tags: quadrilateral

How can we calculate the number of ways in which a $p$-sided polygon can be made inside a $n$-sided polygon such that no side of the $p$-sided polygon is in common with the $n$-sided polygon?

Comment: I can't really see how you would distinguish between the different ways. Isn't building a polygon, a continuous process? I mean, you can always slightly move one vertex ... Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I assume the vertices of the $p$-gon have to be vertices of the $n$-gon. Is that correct? Do you require the $p$-gon to be convex? [If so you presumably require the $n$-gon to be convex].

Comment: As @joriki points out the OP would benefit from looking at the previous question but this question should not be said to be a duplicate just because a particular case has been asked previously.

Comment: @S.Dolan: I think that depends on whether the answer to the other question is easily generalizable. In this case it is. Everyone is free to post the general solution as a comment under the answer or edit it into the answer if it's deemed helpful to state the generalization explicitly; we don't need a separate question for that that's identical except for specific numbers plugged in.

Comment: There is no sense in which this OPs question involves "specific numbers being plugged in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair each one of the $p$ vertices with the adjacent vertex in a clockwise direction. Then all we have to do is count the number of ways of selecting $p$ pairs of adjacent points from the $n$ available.

Let $v$ be one of the $n$ vertices.

**Case 1** 
When $v$ is not one of the $p$ vertices we have to choose  $p$ pairs from a line of $n$ points. We can think of this as the number of arrangements of $p$ pairs and $n-2p$ single points in a line.

**Case 2** 
When $v$ is one of the $p$ vertices we have to choose a further $p-1$ pairs from a line of $n-2$ points.

The total is $\begin{pmatrix}n-p-1\\p-1\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n-p\\p\\\end{pmatrix}$.